# QGIS: Legend not displaying symbology of items

Tags: qgis, legend, layouts

I'm making a plant including power plants in a country. I plotted the plants and their symbology shows up in properties in the legend items but it does not in the legend itself as you can see in the picture below.

*P.S.: Not sure if this is the reason why they might not show up but I used a different symbol size for different capacities as described in this other question: [Categorising point layer twice by size and form in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383545/categorising-point-layer-twice-by-size-and-form-in-qgis/383550#383550)*

**How can I fix this so that the symbols of each plant are shown in the legend?**

[image]

Comment: Select the` Auto update` in the legend items

Comment: By doing this ALL the legend elements show up. I don't want them all to show up in the same legend. I removed a few.

Comment: Even with that Auto-update... the symbols of the plants don't show up

Comment: I cannot see from the screenie but you may have chosen the "Only show items inside linked map"?

Comment: if you chose it, it would show only the items that are currently visible in your map canvas.

Comment: All elements are visible in my map canvas. I just don't need them all in the same legend. Despite including them all and using auto update, the symbols for the plants do not show...

Comment: Hmm.. Can you make share a bigger screenshot so that the other settings are also visible?

Answer (score 3):

Using QGIS 3.16.x you may double-click any symbols in the legend properties dialogue and change their symbology, esp. size, which may be problematic if based on values and/or map units. This should allow you to set the symbols as you need them.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there's a better solution to this. Nonetheless, what did the thrick for me was duplicating the layers of the map containing the power plants but this time only categorising the points once (before they were categorised both by colour and size; now only colour). The layer with 2 categorisations was hidden so I could update the legend in the layout. Then, I locked the legend and went back to the map to make the original layers visible and deleted the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread looking for a similar problem with imported KMZ layer symbology.  My experience may be atypically daft, but if someone else ends up in the same situation:

In my install, 3.26.3-Buenos Aires, imported KMZ vector layers were assigned "Embedded Symbols" - presumably embedded in the KMZ file from Earth.  These did not render as expected (outlines without fill, for example), either on screen or in the composer and not showing at all in the legend.  Changing the layer symbols to "Single Symbol" (appropriate to this map) yielded the expected results with symbol visibility and adjustments.