How to make a heatmap to show the distribution of attribute values more accurately?
I want to be able to create a heatmap that shows the distribution of the attributed "carbon" value within a merged layer.
I have a merged vector point layer that represents the combination of 3 separate marine habitats location point vector datasets.

I have attributed a "carbon" value to each type of marine habitat after merging the 3 separate layers all together after a previous question I put here was answered telling me how to do that. So in the merged layer attribute table there is a "carbon" column with a value for each of the points on the UK.
I have tried doing interpolation based on the mean carbon storage value derived from a grid overlaid on the merged layer; however I don't necessarily want it to interpolate data far outside of where the point data actually is which leading to a confusing output for what I actually want to show. For where the points actually are it is showing me what I want. Please see the image below -  the patches of red/blue are generally accurate, but the amount of green less so.

I have tried just changing the point data layer to a "heatmap" in the symbology tab as well but this doesn't really accurately show the information correctly as how it looks changes at different scales of me zooming in on the map.
If there is a way to get the visual output of the interpolated output more in line to not show data far outside of where the point data actually is, that would be ideal.

Why don't you try a color-coded or color and size-coded dot map? It is far more appropriate for data like this IMHO

How should I go about doing that...?

You could start with this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383545/categorising-point-layer-twice-by-size-and-form-in-qgis

Thank you so much!
